# mysqld.exe keeps crashing

Tags: crash, mysql

I appear to be in a bit of a bind.  I have been working on some simple design changes to our website and having finished went to release them live.  No sooner than I uploaded the affected pages, the MySQL Daemon service crahsed.  I did a restart and then restarted the service as it didn't restart automatically and managed to navigate to the website.  It crashed again and has been doing so nearly every ten minutes like clockwork.

The windows event log is listed here:

```
Log Name:      Application
Source:        Application Error
Date:          14/06/2013 10:03:47
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: (100)
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      DEDICAT-3JPUQIF
Description:
Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.5.28.0, time stamp: 0x503ddca5
Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.5.28.0, time stamp: 0x503ddca5
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000000fd869
Faulting process id: 0x428
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce68dc51cff4c0
Faulting application path: C:Program FilesMySQLMySQL Server 5.5binmysqld.exe
Faulting module path: C:Program FilesMySQLMySQL Server 5.5binmysqld.exe
Report Id: 525bda97-d4d1-11e2-95f3-525400bb8b87
Event Xml:


1000
2
100
0x80000000000000

6821
Application
DEDICAT-3JPUQIF



mysqld.exe
5.5.28.0
503ddca5
mysqld.exe
5.5.28.0
503ddca5
c0000005
00000000000fd869
428
01ce68dc51cff4c0
C:Program FilesMySQLMySQL Server 5.5binmysqld.exe
C:Program FilesMySQLMySQL Server 5.5binmysqld.exe
525bda97-d4d1-11e2-95f3-525400bb8b87
```

Does anybody have any clues what might be causing this?

As always thanks in advance.

Graham

Comment: Please see this question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145643/mysql-stops-running-when-this-stored-procedure-is-executed/17146738#17146738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be an erroneous space character at the end of several lines of a stored procedure generated by SqlYog.  Removing the characters fixed the problem.

Cheers
Graham

Answer (score 0):

When I researched, this error means your database is probably corrupt and needs rebuilding.

Have a look at [MySQL suddenly not working on Windows Server 2003](https://serverfault.com/questions/33472/mysql-suddenly-not-working-on-windows-server-2003) server fault question.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response, I am running an upgrade now, but it still keeps happening.  At the point of pulling my hair out!!!