# Mysql Stops running when this stored procedure is executed

Tags: stored-procedures, mysql

Morning Guys,

This is a follow on from this question.  [mysqld.exe keeps crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108395/mysqld-exe-keeps-crashing).

I have narrowed the crashing down to a single stored procedure which just seems to fall over when this stored procedure gets executed.

I have split it down from its original state to three stored procedures.

The main procedure spProductGroupMenu is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `phclothing`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `spProductGroupMenu`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `spProductGroupMenu`(
spGrp VARCHAR(3),
spProductType ENUM('clothing','parts')
)
BEGIN
DECLARE qryType ENUM('group','manufacturer','nothing');


IF spProductType='clothing' THEN
    SET qryType = (SELECT 
                (CASE WHEN 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(DISTINCT(productGroup)) 
                    FROM 
                        tblclothingitems 
                    WHERE 
                        productGroup=spGrp)>0 
                    THEN 'group' ELSE
                (CASE WHEN 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(DISTINCT(productManufacturer)) 
                    FROM 
                        tblclothingitems 
                    WHERE 
                        productManufacturer=spGrp)>0
                    THEN 'manufacturer' ELSE
                'nothing' END) END));
ELSE
    SET qryType = (SELECT 
                (CASE WHEN 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(DISTINCT(productGroup)) 
                    FROM 
                        tblpartsitems 
                    WHERE 
                        productGroup=spGrp)>0 
                    THEN 'group' ELSE
                (CASE WHEN 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(DISTINCT(productManufacturer)) 
                    FROM 
                        tblpartsitems 
                    WHERE 
                        productManufacturer=spGrp)>0
                    THEN 'manufacturer' ELSE
                'nothing' END) END));
END IF;



IF qryType='manufacturer' THEN

    CALL spPGMMans(spGrp,spProductType,qryType); ************

ELSEIF qryType='group' THEN

    CALL spPGMGrp(spGrp,spProductType,qryType); ************
ELSE
    -- This is not going to be used
    SELECT
        DISTINCT(productgroup) grpCode,
        (CASE WHEN spProductType='clothing' THEN
            CONCAT('/',grpSEO,'.html') 
        ELSE
            CONCAT(spProductType,'/',grpSEO,'.html') END)seoLink,
        pageH1 seoLinkTitle,
        'allGroups' entryType,
        qryType
    FROM
        tblclothingitems ci
    LEFT JOIN
        tblclothinggroups cg
    ON
        ci.productGroup = cg.grpcode
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DISTINCT(productManufacturer) grpCode,
        (CASE WHEN spProductType='clothing' THEN            
            cm.urlExt 
        ELSE
            CONCAT(spProductType,'/',cm.urlExt) END)seoLink,
        manTitle seoLinkTitle,
        'allMans' entryType,
        qryType
    FROM
        tblclothingitems ci
    LEFT JOIN
        tblclothingmanufacturers cm
    ON
        ci.productManufacturer = cm.manCode
    ORDER BY entryType, seoLinkTitle ASC;   
END IF;
END$$
```

DELIMITER ;

This used to consist of a series of queries with union all statements depending on what was passed in but this raised the alarm about the mysql server falling over.  So where the  ************ are is where i have divided the stored procedure into three.  Each of these stored procedures runs on the server in its own right but for some reason when this stored procedure gets called the server just falls over and stops running.

I have been checking the logs throughout and it is when this stored procedure is run that the connection to the server goes.

If anybody has any clues as to why this may be happening or if anybody has had experience of this situation then please let me know.

Many thanks in advance.

Graham

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well this clearly very strange.  Following a hunch I clicked to the end of every line in the stored procedure and removed all white space just in case there were any erroneous non printable characters that were causing an issue, low and behold it seemed to fix it.

To test the theory I then reversed the stored procedure again back to the point when it was causing the server to crash.  I ran it on the server and it worked as well, which is clearly very odd.

Needless to say I am completely dumb-founded as to why this error occurred in the first place but can only presume that it was a non-printing character at the end of a line in the stored procedure.

Cheers if you took a look!
Graham